# How to generate a hexdigest with Groovy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, groovy, hash, hex, digest

I need to sign a request with AWS 4 but I am having issues with the Signature key.

From [Amazon Doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-calculate-signature.html)

> Use the digest (binary format) for the key derivation. Most languages have functions to compute either a binary format hash, commonly called a digest, or a hex-encoded hash, called a hexdigest. The key derivation requires that you use a binary-formatted digest.

So I am able to obtain the Signature key in `byte[]` format but I am not able to format that value as hexdigest.

Comment: Please show your current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it something that you are looking for? `.encodeHex()`

```
byte[] printable = 'Rao'.bytes
println printable
// -> [82, 97, 111]
def printableHex = printable.encodeHex()
println printableHex.toString()
// -> 52616f
```

Comment: Oh okay, I will try with encodeHex(). In that case, could you please add what should be the funciton to use to obtain the digest only? Thanks.

Comment: @uru917 The example there uses the `.bytes` from the string `'Rao'` - which is what you have.